# Accessing element by id on another site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building an xsl/xml catalogue of my card collection, which features links to beckett.com for each card. A piece of functionality I'm hoping to implement is the ability to mouseover the card name and show a preview of the card if one is available. The best way I've found of doing this is to attempt to access the element id "item_image_front" on the page and pass it through to my page.

I have tried using an iframe and jquery's $.get, however I am running into errors. "Get" results in "No access-control-allow-origin header is present on requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access" and the iframe option results in "X-frame-options set to sameorigin".

Am I completely out of luck here, or is there another solution?

Comment: Do you have PHP in your server?

Comment: Proxy on your own server

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy yes, I have php on here. My knowledge of php is very limited, to give fair warning

Comment: You can pass a GET value to PHP and use `readfile` function to prevent headers of the original site. Searching these info isn't difficult.

Comment: do you have access to the another site? Or atleast you need to have access to provide your javascript to the host site owner. Otherwise, the answer is no.

Comment: @KiranShakya no, I am not in any way affiliated with beckett.com.

Comment: then your can not accomplish this with html and javascript only.